# Characteristic polynomial of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I wanted to find the eigenvalues of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, then I could use these two options.

$$\lambda\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{0}$$
$$\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{0}$$

However, which of these equations gives the characteristic polynomial? The sign of each polynomial will differ by a negative. This obviously doesn't matter when finding the eigenvalues as it is equated to $0$, but is one of these more "correct" than the other? Is one considered the characteristic polynomial over the other, or are both acceptable?

Comment: Some people like their characteristic polynomial to be monic and will thus choose the first option. Some people are wild savages and will choose the other.

Comment: I guess I'm a savage because I usually use the second equation -- it has the computational advantage that only terms on the diagonal are changed compared to the original matrix. - Don't think it would matter for a computer, but if you're trying to brute force the determinant by hand, for instance, it can be easier. Theoretically I agree, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Both are acceptable. There is no more reason a priori to use the 2nd version, but it is this one that is used by at least 95% of people.